# Load for-loop results in container

Tags: r, for-loop, containers, least-squares, beta

All of the below is conducted in R.

I am trying to store the result of a for-loop result in different containers, but somehow I keep ending up with NA-warnings and the results are *not* not stored in my container. Even tried different containers for different for-loops within the function and then finally a matrix for the containers, but it seems it's not working.

Already trying different solutions for two full days, and it seems there should be such an easy solution. Maybe I just can't see it myself anymore...

```
data.ols<-data.frame(cbind(rep(1),holiday,weathersit,atemp,hum,windspeed))
y<-as.vector(cnt)
z=c(holiday, weathersit, atemp, hum, windspeed)
z.names=c("holiday","weathersit","atemp","hum","windspeed")
result.container<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=6,ncol=4))
colnames(result.container)<-c("beta","SE","t-statistic","p-value")

ols<-function(y,X2,x=0){
X<-matrix(z, ncol=5)
X2<-cbind(rep(1, nrow(X)), X)
XXinv <- solve(t(X2) %*% X2, diag(ncol(X2))) # Compute (X'X)^-1
beta<-XXinv%*%t(X2)%*%y
print(beta)
result.container[,1]<-beta

result.testdebug<-vector()
for (i in c("V1","holiday","weathersit","atemp","hum","windspeed")){
SE<-sd(i)
result.testdebug[i]<-sd(data.ols[,i])
return(result.testdebug)
result.container[,2]<-result.testdebug}

result.testtvalue<-vector()
for (i in c("V1","holiday","weathersit","atemp","hum","windspeed")){
nominator<-(mean(i)-x)   
t.value <- nominator/sd(i)
return(t.value)
result.testtvalue<-t.value
result.container[,3]<-result.testtvalue}

df <- length(X)-1 
p.value <- 2*pt(t.value, df, lower.tail=FALSE)
return(p.value)
result.container[,4]<-p.value

list(rbind(beta,result.testdebug,t.value,p.value))}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are having some trouble with functions in R. In R, functions have their own environment (i.e. their own set of objects). Even though they can read from their parent environment (the set of all objects), they cannot write on it. Let me demonstrate that with a simpler code.

```
teste2=matrix(,2,2)
teste=function(a,b) {teste2[,1]=c(a,b)}
teste(3,2)
teste2
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA
```

As you can see teste (the function) cannot change teste2 (the matrix).

In R ,the best way to make a function is to give it all the objects it needs as parameters and by the end of the function body, to give a single `return()` function that gives the final object.

You did something close to that, but used multiple `return()` functions. R only uses the first `return()` and ignores the rest. See below:

```
teste=function(a,b) {c=a;return(c);d=b;return(d)}
teste(3,2)
[1] 3
```

For your particular code, I reccomend excluding all result.container<- and put return() only on the end, around that last (list)